# How to use two nested lists to make a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two nested nested lists, like this one:

```
list_1 = [[100, 90, 90, 85, 70], [100, 90, 90, 85, 80], [105, 100, 90, 90, 85]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]]
```

I want to use the elements in `list_1` with `list_2` to make a dictionary but it needs to be in the form of a nested list, the output should be like this:

```
[{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,70:4},{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,80:4},{105:1,100:2,90:3,90:3,85:4}]
```

Is there any way in Python 3 to do this?

Comment: How should the `actual` dictionary look like?

Comment: Do you mean your output should be `[{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,70:4},{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,80:4}]` etc?

Comment: @DanielLenz yes

Comment: The output still doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Dicts can't have duplicate items like `90:2,90:2`.

Comment: And is it intentional that your keys (from list_1) are not unique within one dict? This means that the latest entry will overwrite the previous ones:
`In [1]: {'a': 1, 'a': 2}
Out[1]: {'a': 2}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to zip zips:

```
>>> [dict(zip(*z)) for z in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[{70: 4, 85: 3, 90: 2, 100: 1},
 {80: 4, 85: 3, 90: 2, 100: 1},
 {85: 4, 90: 3, 100: 2, 105: 1}]
```

Or maybe you wanted strings, keeping duplicate "keys":

```
>>> [[f'{a}:{b}' for a,b in zip(*z)] for z in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[['100:1', '90:2', '90:2', '85:3', '70:4'],
 ['100:1', '90:2', '90:2', '85:3', '80:4'],
 ['105:1', '100:2', '90:3', '90:3', '85:4']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
list(map(dict, map(zip, list_1, list_2)))
```

Which I find very pleasing.